# Return Players With Ability To Play All Same Positions

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, relational-division

I want to be able to support searching for a player

Let us say "Babe Ruth". I search for that player's name.

I want to return a query of only players that played ALL the same positions as babe ruth along with their batting average and homerun_count. So, Babe Ruth played outfield and pitcher, so we want players that played both positions.

Players(id, name, batting_avg, homerun_count, rookie_season, retired_season)

Positions(players_id, position)

```
PLAYERS Table
id  | name       | batting_avg | homerun_count | rookie_season | retired_season
1   | Babe Ruth  |   .342      |    714        |     1914      |    1935
2   | Travis Wood|   .143      |      1        |      2010     |    2020
3   | Barry Bonds|   .298      |     762       |      1986     |    2007

Positions
players_id | position
    1      | Pitcher
    1      | Outfield
    2      | Pitcher
    2      | Outfield
    3      | Outfield
```

So we would return Travis Wood as:

```
name         | id | batting_average | homerun_count
Travis Wood  | 2  |     .143        |      1
```

Comment: Players who played exactly the same positions (not less and not more) or players that played at least these positions (not less but maybe more)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a relational division problem.

I would recommend a join to bring all positions of each player, and filtering with a `exists` condition on positions that Babe Ruth played at. Then, you can use a `having` clause to ensure that all positions were found.

```
select pl.*
from players pl
inner join positions po on po.player_id = pl.id
where pl.name <> 'Babe Ruth' and exists (
    select 1
    from players pl1
    inner join positions po1 on po1.player_id = pl1.id
    where pl1.name = 'Babe Ruth' and po1.position = po.Position
)
group by pl.id
having count(*) = (
    select count(*) 
    from players pl1
    inner join positions po1 on po1.player_id = pl1.id
    where pl1.name = 'Babe Ruth'
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=41db78f3984a29d996e2d77b353a2fb4)**:

```
id | name        | batting_avg | homerun_count | rookie_season | retired_season
-: | :---------- | ----------: | ------------: | ------------: | -------------:
 2 | Travis Wood |       0.143 |             1 |          2010 |           2020
```

Comment: Would this scale? Let us say that we have a player that plays shortstop, first base, outfield, and pitcher. We would include him in since he plays outfield and pitcher based off the Babe Ruth example. I am curious if this scales if the amount of positions a player has goes past 2 as seen in this example.

Comment: @emilyroberts2298: if a player has all the positions that Babe Ruth has, plus other positions, the query returns him. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46ba6a73b2ed52e253d0519c6fae109d

Answer (score 0):

This method aggregates all the positions, so you can get an exact match on them:

```
with po as (
      select po.players_id, group_concat(position order by position) as positions
      from positions po 
      group by po.players_id
     ) 
select p.* 
from players p join
     po
     on po.players_id = p.id join
     (select po2.*
      from po po2 
      where po2.players_id = (select p2.id from players p2 where p2.name = 'Babe Ruth')
     ) p_br
     on b_br.positions = po.positions;
```

EDIT:

If you just want all of Babe Rush's positions and some others (possibly):

```
with po as (
      select p.*, po.position
      from players p join
           positions po 
           on po.players_id = p.id
     ) 
select po.name, po.id, po.batting_average, po.homerun_count
from po pobr left join
     po
     on pobr.position = po.position
where pobr.name = 'Babe Ruth'
group by po.name, po.id, po.batting_average, po.homerun_count
having count(*) = count(pobr.name);
```

Comment: Would this still work if we had to search for players that can play 3 positions. Also, if there was a player that could play 5 positions with all 3 positions based off what we are looking for. I would want that/those players returned still.

Comment: @emilyroberts2298 . . . My interpretation of your question is that you wanted *exact* matches on the positions, not a supersetting relationship.  That's why I suggest using string aggregation for this purpose.

Comment: I originally thought that too. But need to return players that share those positions, but also possibly additional ones. Could you show how to do that? So if there was a player that plays 3 with two being pitcher and outfield we would need to return him. Sorry, I was not just going for an exact match, but just players that share with that searched one.